# How to show progress bar until a webview open in android

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-progressbar

As soon as the Activity started from intent, need to display a ProgressBar. Once WebView is displayed, then ProgressBar need to be hidden.But not able to show ProgressBar in screen. Below is my xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

below is my Activity,

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG= WebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    String url=null;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar=null;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        //getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        this.url=intent.getStringExtra("url");

        webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webView.loadUrl(url);


       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
}


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                AndroidLogger.log(5,TAG," error response"+error);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                AndroidLogger.log(5,TAG,"started"+url);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

           }

        });
    }

}
```

After starting Intent for WebViewActivity, instead of showing ProgressBar getting a blank white screen, until WebView opens up. So how to solve this. Anybody help with this.

Comment: Check whether you progress color is same as your background so that it is not visible to us. Try giving `android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/black"` on `ProgressBar`.

Comment: @Antonio I have tried like you said. But no change..

Comment: Does the progress bar display in the preview of Android studio? If not, then something might be wrong with it.

Comment: @Vucko yes I can able to see in preview. but not in mobile screen

Comment: @Kousalya try changing visibility of webview to gone instead of invisible. Invisible makes it not visible but the view is there. Sometimes the progress bar is below the webview in this case. If it is given as gone, then it will not be present.

Comment: @Antonio already I tried changing it.but that also not worked

Comment: @Kousalya You have made the progress invisible in onReceivedError and onPageFinishes right? Check whether any of these overriding methods are called as soon as you enter the activity. Try logging in both methods. Maybe the progress bar is being invisible since any of the method is called.

Comment: @Antonio yes right. But I can able to see a blank screen before loading webview. How to overcome that case.

Comment: @Kousalya is any of the methods called at the beginning itself?

Comment: @Antonio pageFinished method is getting called in 0.25 secs..may be this is a reason?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214322/discussion-between-antonio-and-kousalya).

Comment: Use [ContentLoadingProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/ContentLoadingProgressBar) because it was built for this, it has a delay built into it

Comment: Adding Progressbar in Activity and not in Xml solves my issue

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file seems correct BUT  your java file having unnecessary code stuff. just adding progress bar in xml will not work. you need to hide/show inside your java file.
correct it step by step and follow this.

```
    public class WebViewActivity extends Activity implements Listener {
    String TAG= PaymentGatewayActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    String url=null;
    String deviceType="ANDROID", name, password, code, pId=null;
    String cur=null;
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar=null;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.payment_progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AndroidLogger.log(5,TAG,"progress bar made visible");
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        this.pId=intent.getStringExtra("pId");
        // HERE CALLING RETROFIT
        CommunicationManager communicationManager = new CommunicationManager(WebViewActivity.this, this,pId );
        communicationManager.getLink("get url");

    }
//THIS METHOD WILL INVOKED WHEN GETTING SUCCESS RESPONSE
    @Override
    public void getUrlSuccessResponse(String url, String pId, String cur) {

        this.url = url;
        this.pId = pId;
        this.cur = cur;
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.name = sharedpreferences.getString(this.getResources().getString(R.string.name), "");
        this.password = sharedpreferences.getString(this.getResources().getString(R.string.password), "");
        this.code = sharedpreferences.getString(this.getResources().getString(R.string.code), "");
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) //set this one to remove unnecessary background

        //setup custom webview client here
        webView.setWebViewClient(new PayWeb());


        //load url inside webview
        try {        
            String postData = "type=" + URLEncoder.encode("ANDROID", "UTF-8") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&code=" + URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8") + "&cur=" + URLEncoder.encode(cur, "UTF-8") + "&name=" + URLEncoder.encode(subscriberId, "UTF-8") + "&pId=" + URLEncoder.encode(pId, "UTF-8");
            webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class PayWeb extends WebViewClient{
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return false; // then it is not handled by default action
            }


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                //show progressbar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                    
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                //hide progressbar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                    
            }    
        }

    @Override
    public void getUrlFailureResponse(int statusCode, String status) {
        //manage webpage faliour case
    }

    @Override
    public void getUrlNetworkFailureException(int statusCode, String status) {
        //manage network faliour case
    }
}
```